# ResourcesNotFoundException exception

Tags: android, android-fragments

I get ResourcesNotFoundException exception when I use resources  from `progress.xml` file.

My complete code below Error, class.java, progress.xml file.

Err in Logcat

```
09-04 00:39:04.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 00:39:04.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17837): Process: developer.mohab.gymee, PID: 17837
09-04 00:39:04.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17837): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{developer.mohab.gymee/developer.mohab.gymee.Cardio.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
09-04 00:39:04.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17837):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
09-04 00:39:04.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17837):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
09-04 00:39:04.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17837):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
09-04 00:39:04.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17837):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
09-04 00:39:04.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17837):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-04 00:39:04.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17837):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
09-04 00:39:04.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17837):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
09-04 00:39:04.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17837):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-04 00:39:04.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17837):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-04 00:39:04.700: E/AndroidRuntime(17837):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
```

Class returns this error

```
 public static class Progress extends Fragment {
    TextView Abs ;
    TextView Per ;
    MainActivity mainActivity ;
    Database database ;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        database = new Database(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress,container,false);
        Abs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.above);
        Per = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.below);
        Prgress_Limits();
        return view ;
    }
    public  void Prgress_Limits(){
        Cursor cursor ;
        cursor = getCursor();
        int LAST_INPUT ;
        int FIRST_INPUT ;
        if(cursor!=null&&cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int VALUE_COLUMN = cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Cardio_chart.Values.VALUE);
            FIRST_INPUT = cursor.getInt(VALUE_COLUMN);
            cursor.moveToLast();
            LAST_INPUT = cursor.getInt(VALUE_COLUMN);
            int abs = LAST_INPUT-FIRST_INPUT ;
            Abs.setText(abs);
            int per = (abs*100)/FIRST_INPUT ;
            Per.setText(per+" %");
        }
        else {
            Abs.setText(00);
            Per.setText(00+" %");
        }


    }
    public Cursor getCursor() {
        Cursor c;
        String Selection;
        Cursor check;
        ContentResolver hesolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        check = hesolver.query(DatabaseFilter.ValueTable(), null, null, null, null);
        Cursor check2;
        ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        check2 = resolver.query(DatabaseFilter.LimitTable(), null, null, null, null);
        if (check != null && check.moveToFirst() && check2 != null && check2.moveToFirst()) {
            int Offset = offset();
            int Limit = limit();
            Selection = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseFilter.valueTable_Name() + " LIMIT " + Limit + " OFFSET " + Offset + ";";
            SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();
            c = db.rawQuery(Selection, null);
        } else {
            ContentResolver sesolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
            c = sesolver.query(DatabaseFilter.ValueTable(), null, null, null, null);
        }
        return c;
    }
    public int offset() {
        Cursor save;
        ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        save = resolver.query(DatabaseFilter.LimitTable(), null, null, null, null);
        save.moveToLast();
        int high = save.getColumnIndex(Contract.Cardio_chart.Limits.HIGH);
        int Offset = save.getInt(high);
        save.close();
        return Offset;
    }

    public int limit() {

        Cursor h;
        ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        h = resolver.query(DatabaseFilter.ValueTable(), null, null, null, null);
        h.moveToLast();
        int id = h.getColumnIndex(Contract.Cardio_chart.Values._ID);
        int last_chart_input = h.getInt(id);
        int Offset = offset();
        int Limit = last_chart_input - Offset;
        h.close();
        return Limit;
    }
}
```

}

i get this error when i use any resources from `progress.xml` file

Progress.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:id="@+id/relative">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/progress"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Progress"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:textColor="#ff538dff"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_dialog_padding_top_material"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="        absolute"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_bar_icon_vertical_padding_material"
    android:textColor="#ffffb75d"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/above"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView4" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/above"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    android:background="#ffd8f1ff"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="        percentage"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_bar_icon_vertical_padding_material"
    android:textColor="#ffffbd56"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/below"
    android:background="#ffd8f1ff"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/above"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/above"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/above" />
```

Comment: Yet another... Stop using some random int values where overloaded function expect charsequence or interest resources... 00 == 0 and is int, not string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont put integer when you set the text, use strings instead

```
Abs.setText("00");
Per.setText("00 %");
```

If you wanted to use ressource as an alternative then here is an example:

```
Abs.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.zero_string));
```